# Optimize/Concise the conditional code in q kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table t based on which I have to assign value to variable v.

```
q)t:([] sym:`goog`amzn; px:100 200);
q)v:$[count dv:exec distinct sym from t where px=101;dv;enlist`default]; 
/ return distinct syms in case of satisfied condition from t as return enlist symbol.
```

Is there a way to make the conditional code concise?(by getting rid of temporary variable dv or any other alternative)

Comment: Hopefully not off-topic, but why do you need ```enlist` ```if `dv` is empty?

Comment: Thanks, agreed on that.(Modified example a bit). If dv is empty then its value will be symbol$()(empty list) which is different from enlist` (singleton list) --> (enlist` )~ `symbol$() /- output 0b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to introduce a temporary variable, don't:

```
q)v:$[count v:exec distinct sym from t where px=100;v;enlist`default];
```

It's common practice in q to reuse a variable several times in a single expression.

Or you can create a simple function and use it whenever you need to replace an empty list with a singleton list:

```
q)withDefault:{$[count y;y;enlist x]}
q)withDefault[`default] exec distinct sym from t where px > 100
,`amzn
q)withDefault[`default] exec distinct sym from t where px > 1000
,`default
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use an `if` instead of an if-else:

```
if[not count v:exec distinct sym from t where px=101;v:1#`default];
```